# Reporting units for user and system CPU usage for individual process via collectd

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, process, operating-system, collectd

I've been using the [collectd:Process Plugin](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml#plugin_processes) to monitor the per process metrics on a Linux server I'm running. It is just that there are no information about the units for which process use the CPU time.

From the embedded link,

> The statistics collected for matched processes are: - size of the resident segment size (RSS) - user- and system-time used - number of processes - number of threads - number of open files (under Linux) - number of memory mapped files (under Linux) - io data (where available) - context switches (under Linux) - minor and major pagefaults

One one of the plots I made from a Graphic tool called Grafana, here is the raw output it was plotting for one of the applications.

Would like to know what unit that data is reported.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's microseconds.
"Processes plugin, like other plugins, report ps_cputime metric in microseconds of used CPU time."
 -- Refered from this post. https://github.com/collectd/collectd/issues/2862